# To capture the warning thrown by the R script using R.NET

Tags: r

When I use the below script in R Console it gave me the output as  string "Warning"

```
jj = ts(scan("jj.dat"),  start=1960, frequency=4)  
tryCatch(arima(jj, 
         order = c(1, 0,1)), 
         warning=function(w) cat("Warning"))
```

I tried to use the same code in R.NET and expected to get the string "Warning", but I'm getting Parser Exception showing "Code error". Below is the code snippet which I tried in R.NET.

```
try
{
   string script = "tryCatch(arima(jj, 
                             order = c(4, 0,6)), 
                             warning=function(w) cat(\"Warning\"))";
   string str=engine.EagerEvaluate("script").AsCharacter().First();//*
}catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

Kindly throw to me some idea, on how can we tackle this issue. Or is there any other way to capture the R Script warnings and error messages in R.NET.

Comment: Parser errors in R.NET are errors in the underlying R-code in all cases I ever encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience in these kind of R integration into other languages (rpy, coupling python and R) I would keep the amount of R source code inside .NET at a minimum. The way I would go would be to write a function inside a .R file which does what you want.

```
hello = function() { print("Hello World") }
```

Saving this function inside `spam.r` allows you to use `source` in order to load this new function into the R session running inside .NET. Then you can a very simple R script:

```
source("spam.r")
hello()
```

This is ofcourse a quite trivial example, but `hello` could contain much more complicated code. In this way you prevent any errors because of writing the R code in .NET (in rpy there where some problems with that, e.g. data.frame was not allowed). Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks paul. Your suggetions works fine. But, to full fill my requirement completely this is not enough. I can't accommodate all my requirements in R script side. There should be to-and-fro communication. I guess this will be another hurdle.

Comment: I understand, but in principle i would limit the amount of R code in. NET. Ofcourse that is not always possible.